# Trouble instantiating prefab object by calling function in external script (Unity/C#)

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am having trouble getting one script to call an instantiation function from another script. The following image illustrates how I have my game objects set up.

[image]

I have 2 object things, Thing1 and Thing2, which move around the screen based on a movement script that is attached to each of them. Thing1 also has attached a reaction script. When Thing1 and Thing2 collide, Thing 3 should appear. Thing3 has an instantiation script attached to it that contains a function with an instantiation command.

When I call the instantiation function within the instantiation script (I put it in the Start function of Thing3), it works fine. However, when I take it out of there and try to put it in the Start function of the reaction script attached to Thing2 I cannot get it to work. Most currently, I get no error on compiling but as soon as the game starts I get is the following (The behavior of Thing1 and Thing2 also seems to be adversely affected):

```
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

When I look up the reason for that error I find that the most typical reason for that is a prefab object not being attached to the script. However, I DO have a prefab attached to the script. It is attached to the instantiation script that contains the instantiation function.

Below is the code for the instantiation script and the reaction script that is calling the instantiation function within the instatiation script.

```
//Instantiation
public class Thing3Instantiation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject thing3Obj;

    void Start()
    {
        //CreateThing3();
    }

    public void CreateThing3()
    {
        Instantiate(thing3Obj);
    }
}
```

And

```
//Reaction
public class Reaction : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Thing3Instatiation thing3instantiation;

    void Awake()
    {
        thing3instantiation = GetComponent<Thing3Instantiation>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        thing3instantiation.CreateThing3();   //This line triggers the null error
    }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error message should tell you the exact line that the error is exception is occurring; you should mark that line in your code samples.

Comment: Also, I'm gonna go ahead and guess that the null reference is `transition` in your `Reaction` script.  How is that defined and how is it set?

Comment: Edited. `transition.CreateTransition` should be `thing3instantiation.CreateThing3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly:

- **Reaction** is on Thing1
- **Thing3Instantiation** is on Thing3

So when Reaction *awakes*, it tries to find the component called Thing3Instantiation on its own gameObject (Thing1). But it isn't on Thing1 it is on Thing3, so `GetComponent` returns `null`.

Hence, your NullReferenceException.

Comment: Correct. But I am calling the Thing3Instantiation function from the Reaction script. And I have created an instance of the Thing3Instantiation class within the Reaction script. So at the point of calling/invoking the instantiation function ( `thing3instantiation.CreateThing3();` ), doesn't the Thing3Instantiation script take over? And if so, and if the Thing3 prefab is attached to the Thing3Instantiation script, why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Siggytron You have created a variable of type `Thing3Instatiation` but you have no actual reference to an instance of it. In your `Awake` function you try to get this reference using `GetComponent`. This is the point: `GetComponent` only searches the same GameObject to which the `Reaction` script is attached. If a script of type `Thing3Instatiation` does not exist on the same GameObject as `Reaction`, `GetComponent` will return `null`. In your start function `thing3instantiation.CreateThing3()` is the same as calling `null.CreateThing3()`, throwing the exception.

Comment: Good explanation. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually at the line of `Instantiate(thing3Obj);`.

In other words... When you Instantiate a script, you won't have variables assigned, in your case `thing3Obj`.  No matter if you've assigned them through Inspector, when Instanciated, you get a clean copy of that class, unallocated. You need to assign it before calling, that's why it's giving the Null exception.

Comment: That's interesting. Why does the Instantiate(thing3Obj) command work when I invoke it in the Start function of the Thing3Instantiation script but not work when I invoke it by calling the instantiation function from the Reaction script?

Comment: Also, how would I go about assigning it? Would I create a public game object in the Reaction script the same as in the Instantiation script and drag the prefab to it? So I would have the prefab attached both the Reaction script component AND the Instantiation script component?  Thanks. Just trying to understand.

Comment: @Siggytron I am still not entirely familiar with your project, but Instantiating a script does require to assigne the values like those, since Unity is a component based Engine. This is true if the script is not in the scene, then you could do like you mention in the comment or create a Singleton class, Resources folder etc... depends on quantity and how often are used.